# Add Font Awesome to Webform Placeholder

Tags: webforms

I am currently using Webform 7.x-4.2 and am looking to add a Font Awesome icon inside the placeholder. I did try modifying the settings.php with the following line:

```
$conf['webform_allowed_tags'] = array('a', 'em', 'strong', 'code', 'img', 'i');
```

My understanding was that this would allow me to use an 'i' tag on my webforms but it is not working for a placeholder. It does work if I use the tag in place of my label but then when a user gets a confirmation email with a submission summary the label shows the 'i' tag (ex. )

Is there a way to use Font Awesome in a placeholder?

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: I think this answer will be good for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/19350349

Comment: Thanks. I saw that in my searches but it does not seem to be working for me. FYI - To call the Font Awesome icons I am using the Bootstrap CDN method.

Answer (score 1):

After reading question again I was way off. I am not sure if there is an easy cut and dry way to do this but I did find a workaround with hook_preprocess_webform_element. The code is pretty rough but should point the way to suit your needs.

Example:

```
function MY_MODULE_preprocess_webform_element(&$variables) {
 $icons = array(
  'fa-adn' => '&#xf170;',
  'fa-align-right' => '&#xf209;',
 );
 if (isset($variables['element']['#attributes']['placeholder']) && array_search($variables['element']['#attributes']['placeholder'], array_keys($icons)) !== FALSE) {
  $icon = $variables['element']['#attributes']['placeholder'];
  $search_string = implode('|', array_keys($icons));
  $variables['element']['#children'] = preg_replace('/^(<input .*placeholder=")(' . $search_string . ')(".*\/>)$/', '$1' . $icons[$icon] . '$3', $variables['element']['#children']);
 }
}
```

This will allow the editor to put the fa icon name in the placeholder text field on the edit form.

You can find the codes for the fa icons [here](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/).

**EDIT:** I forgot to add that you would have to change the font-family for the element and then remove it when the placeholder disappears if you are not using FA for your sites font.

**Edit2:** Per comment you can add a wrapper class to the textfield when editing the component then use CSS to have an icon permanently in front of the textfield.

```
.textfield-wrapper::before {
  position: relative;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  margin-left: 5px;
  content: '\f061';
 }
```

**Note:** If you want the icon 'inside' the text field you can add the appropriate top, left positioning and z-index to this CSS.

Comment: Thanks for this. Works but I am stil needing one further step. I can now get the icon to appear but if I want to add a text after it the icon will disappear. Anyway to add text after the fa-adn?

Comment: Oh ok, that goes against the natural function of the form placeholder. My solution is much more complicated than you need for that. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19285640/font-awesome-icon-inside-text-input-element#19291132) solution it will probably be closer to what you want. You should be able to do it through the GUI and CSS.